# printlist/createlist function not working in linked list

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

My code for linked list is supposed to be printing at least something after the arranged data but it is not printing anything even though there are no errors in compilations and runtime.

What could be the problem?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct data {
    char name[16];
    int subj1, subj2, subj3, total_score;
} data;

data stud[10];

typedef struct LINK {
    data score;
    struct LINK *next;
} LINK;

LINK create_list(data s[], int  length);
void print_list(LINK *LINK);

int main(void) {
    int i;
    int length = 10;

    FILE *fp = fopen("student.txt", "r");
    printf("***Data collected***\n");
    printf("Name             (1) (2) (3)\n");

    LINK create_list(data stud[10], int length);
    void print_list(LINK create_list);

    for (i=0; i<length; ++i) {
        while (fgets(stud[i].name, 16, fp) != 0) {
        fscanf(fp, " %d %d %d ", &stud[i].subj1, &stud[i].subj2, &stud[i].subj3);
            stud[i].total_score = stud[i].subj1 + stud[i].subj2 + stud[i].subj3;
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

LINK create_list(data s[], int length) {
    LINK *head, *temp;
    head = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        temp = head;
        head = (LINK*)malloc(sizeof(data));
        head->score = s[i];
        head->next = temp;
    }
    return *head;
}

void print_list(LINK *p) {
    printf("\n%s\n", p->score.name);    
}
```

I would like it to print in the following way:

```
Eom Ji Chuk         97  85  80
Kim Wang Jjang      70  47  55
Oh Se Yong          50  65  47
Bus Card Chung      12  75  100
Haek Honey Jam      80  83  81
Kong Jeong Cheo     100 100 100
Dap Jeong you       70  70  70  
Lip Took Twi        100 100 99
Lim Woo Jin         24  21  20
Bur ger King        43  99  79
```

I am supposed to be using linked list to create a list and print the list as shown but I could not even print the name.

It seems like **create_list** function and **print_list** function are not working. 
Please tell me which part am I doing wrong?

Comment: your create list is return a pointer to your head node, but you are not assigning the return value to a pointer

Comment: You are not calling `print_list` anywhere. Also, you have conflicting declarations of `print_list`.